# Oxford/Cambridge Sanskrit Book

Tags: language

A few years ago I came across a book on Sanskrit that belonged to the "Classical Language Series" from either Oxford or Cambridge -- about a 1000 pages. I later came across it in google scholar or other service that digitized the book and made it available to the public. I am trying to find this book. Can you help?

Comment: I hope you manage to locate it, but this is not really a question about Hinduism.

Comment: Hi CDR, I would agree at some level, but I was told that culture travels through language. That's why we call the people by the language they speak (French, Spanish, etc). I think there is no "Indian Culture" because there is no "Indian Language". The idea of Hinduism is a false foreign (European) construct that we have naively accepted. A Tamilian man would find very little in common with a Kashmiri even though you would call bot them them hindu.

Comment: True :) But see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and maybe [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/748/should-we-close-questions-related-to-sanskrit-language-and-grammar-as-off-topic) too.

Comment: Agreed. I will take the question to the Linguistics community. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, no problem. Again, hope you find it!

Comment: Thanks CDR -- I followed your direction and asked the question on the Linguistics site and found the book right away!(https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46732/oxford-cambridge-sanskrit-book?noredirect=1#comment108858_46732(

Comment: That's wonderful! You may want to notify the user who found your book and ask them to post it as an answer so you can upvote/accept it. They won't be notified otherwise since they're not following the post. [Use a comment along the lines of  _'@Colin Fine - thanks, you found my book! Feel free to make that into an answer.'_] | Your choice, of course, but it would be nice to do if you wished :)

Comment: @CDR I did so, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the information you provided is limited, I'll provide you with a list of few renowned Sanskrit books from the "Classical Language Series" published by Oxford and Cambridge. Please note that availability in digital form may vary.

1."A Sanskrit Grammar" by William Dwight Whitney (Oxford)

2."A Sanskrit-English Dictionary" by Monier Monier-Williams (Oxford)

3."The Nāṭyaśāstra: English Translation with Critical Notes" by Adya Rangacharya (Oxford)

4."Kālidāsa: Three Plays" by Leonard Nathan and Shailendra Kumar Jain (Oxford)

5."The Upanishads: A New Translation" by Swami Nikhilananda (Ramakrishna-Vivekananda Center)

I hope you may find in this, Happy Learning!!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I was looking for a boon on Sanskrit itself (not grammer or dictionary or works of literature). The book looked at the history of how the language developed from proto-indo-european and also words borrowed from Tamil and Kannada into Sanskrit at Vedic times (shows those other languages were equally ancient).

Comment: Thanks Surya Kiran. The book I was looking for turned out to be by a classic by Burrow (pub. Faber and Faber) and was under the series "Great Languages"). See comment above as well.